# selectKinds is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm newbie in Vue.js. I'm trying to use `v-for` like this:

```html
<tbody v-for="item in handbookSiz.Items" :key="item.company_department_id">
    <tr>
       <td class="label" colspan="9">
          <div class="tbody__icon">
             <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="tbody__text">
              Plot №{{ item.company_department_id }}
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dropdown">
     <td colspan="9">
        <table>
             <tbody v-for="kind in selectKinds(item.kind_title)" :key="kind.siz_id">
                 ...
             </tbody>
       </table>
```

`item.kind_title` is an object that contains another objects. And I need to select some objects from them. For this purpose I've wrote function `selectKinds` in the `computed` section:

```js
selectKinds (item) {
    let obj = item
    let selectedKinds = []

    for(let key in obj) {
       if((key == 'workclothes') || (key == 'siz')) {
          selectedKinds.push(obj[key])
       }
    }

    return selectedKinds
}
```

That's how my `computed` section looks:

```js
computed: {
        filterData () {
            const query = this.plot
            let filteredData = []
            let obj = this.handbookWorkers.Items

            for(let key in obj) {
                let el = obj[key]

                if(el.company_department_id.indexOf(query) != -1) {
                    filteredData.push(el)
                }
            }

            return filteredData
        },
        selectKinds (item) {
            let obj = item
            let selectedKinds = []

            for(let key in obj) {
                if((key == 'workclothes') || (key == 'siz')) {
                    selectedKinds.push(obj[key])
                }
            }

            return selectedKinds
        }
    }
```

I get an error "selectKinds is not a function" in the console.

Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its because you want to call function defined in `computed` but this function is called automatically on get property. If you want to filter you can move to the `methods` they are public methods.

Comment: @daremachine I need to return a new array of objects to use `v-for`. That's why I put function in `computed`. If I'll put it in `methods`, I won't be able to return nothing and `v-for` will fail. Right?

Comment: Your function always return new array so i don't see any problem.

Comment: Your function always return new array so i don't see any problem. You write regular filter function. Also you can use {{ selectKinds = item.kind_title}}. If you set variable selectKinds then is computed function returned.

Comment: @daremachine Sorry, but I don't understand. All filter functions that I wrote before, were in `computed`. I used them in the same way, and there were no problems with them. `filterData ()` in my code is an example.

Why have I got this error now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `computed` detects internal properties and returns calculated results.

To set the value on `computed`, you must use setter.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Please refer to the code below.

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return  {
      selectedKinds: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectKinds: {
      set (item) {
        let obj = item
 
        for (let key in obj) {
           if((key == 'workclothes') || (key == 'siz')) {
             this.selectedKinds.push(obj[key])
           }
        }
      },
      get () {
        return this.selectedKinds
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [{
        company_department_id: 1,
        kind_title: {
          siz_id: 11,
          workclothes: 'asd',
          siz: 'aaa'
        }
      },
      {
        company_department_id: 2,
        kind_title: {
          siz_id: 21,
          siz: 'bbb'
        }
      },
      {
        company_department_id: 3,
        kind_title: {
          siz_id: 31
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    newItems() {
      let list = this.items.map(v => {
        v.selectedKinds = this.selectKinds(v.kind_title)
        return v
      })
      return list
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectKinds(item) {
      let obj = item
      let selectedKinds = []

      for (let key in obj) {
        if ((key === 'workclothes') || (key === 'siz')) {
          selectedKinds.push(obj[key])
        }
      }

      return selectedKinds
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody v-for="item in newItems" :key="item.company_department_id">
      <tr>
        <td class="label" colspan="9">
          <div class="tbody__icon">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="tbody__text">
            Plot №{{ item.company_department_id }}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="dropdown">
        <td colspan="9">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td v-for="(kind,i) in item.selectedKinds" :key="i">{{kind}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```